# Filtering daily data over many years for a specific month(s) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, filter

I have daily data for a sequence of dates

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1915/01/01"),as.Date("2016/12/31"),"day")
```

```
> length(dates)
  [1] 37256
```

How would I go about pulling out July for every year? I know how to subset, but would prefer not to have a separate object for each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by extracting the month and filtering on that:

```
# base R
dates[format(dates, "%m") == "07"]
dates[format(dates, "%B") == "July"] # locale-dependent

# lubridate
library(lubridate)
dates[month(dates) == 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to use `%b`

```
dates[format(dates, "%b) == "Jul"]
```